# Exception AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to use AutoMapper but I get this  exception "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping".
below is my code I can't see what am I missing

```
// Mapping:
CreateMap<Entities.SKill, Skill>();
CreateMap<Entities.Status,Status>();
CreateMap<Entities.MyClass, MyClass>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.Status));

// My entity
public class MyClass:
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SKill> SKills { get; set; }
}

// My contract class:
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId  { get; set; }
    public  Status  Status { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running AutoMapper's `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`? You might get some useful information from this.

The mapping of `Status` looks a bit suspicious. Try removing either of `CreateMap<Entities.Status,Status>();` or `.ForMember(dest => dest.Status, src => src.MapFrom(x => x.Status));`

Comment: thank you I used  AssertConfigurationIsValid  ang get this exception Mapper Not initialized. Call initialize with proper configuration

Comment: @joe - you need to Initialize the Mapper before running AssertConfigurationIsValid. Mapper.Initialize(cfg => [your mapper config])...

Comment: I use .Net core , so the method is AddAutoMapper instead of Initialize